# Showing wrong views in rails application, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a rails app and created a controller. In the Controller class, I created a method called index and set the route as resources :controller_name.
When I am creating the server and visit localhost:3000/controller_name, it is showing the index view, when I visit localhost:3000/controller_name/index,
An error is showing, which is "The action 'show' could not be found for CategoriesController"

I was just wondering about the valid reason.I created an action called show and the error has gone.

Answer (score 0):

When you create routes using "resources :controller_name" default routes for CRUD operations are created. 
Here, you have created a route for the action 'show' but it is not yet defined in the controller.
To see the routes you currently have, run rake:routes in your terminal.
You can read more about resources and CRUD operations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)